# Como desativar (parar, remover, excluir) o versionamento git de um repositório

Tags: git, versionamento

Clonei um repositório do GitHub em meu diretório, porém ele veio cheio de *commits*, ou seja, versionado. Queria reiniciá-lo como um repositório, do zero, como faço?

Já tentei o comando: `git reset` (não deu certo).

O que eu quero é o **contrário do comando `git init`**

Comment: você quer clonar um repositório mas quer que ele venha sem commits?

Comment: @athosbr99 Acho que o Bruno quer apagar o historial dos commits... honestamente, não consigo imaginar uma situação em que quizesse fazer isso. Acho sempre importante preservar o historial.

Comment: Imaginei fazer isso para poder fazer o primeiro commit no GitHub como um repositório recém inicializado. Sem os commits que vieram quando clonei o repositório de outra pessoa. Existe @dcastro uma melhor forma de fazer isto, ou isto não é uma boa prática?

Comment: O repositório que clonaste também está alojado no GitHub? Se sim, o melhor é fazer "fork" para obter uma copia do repositório

Comment: De qualquer das maneiras, acho que se deve manter sempre o historial. Podes sempre fazer push do clone para o github com o historial antigo.

Comment: Conheço um antigo professor da faculdade que lhe foi pedido para ajudar a encontrar um bug num projecto duma empresa. Uma tarefa que devia ter durado 1 ou 2 dias, demorou semanas, porque alguém decidiu apagar todo o historial e não havia maneira de descobrir *quando* o bug foi introduzido.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Apague a pasta oculta `.git` dentro do repositório e execute `git init` para iniciar um novo historial.

Answer (score 9):

Consegui com o seguinte comando no linux/ubuntu

```
rm -rf .git
```

Comment: git rm -rf .git

Comment: Acho que essa foi a melhor solução, não sei pq não está como resposta correta.

Comment: A melhor solução mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Como já foi respondido pelo dcastro, basta remover a pasta `.git` que se encontra dentro do repositório. Assim, você pode começar de novo.

Se, por algum motivo, você não quiser baixar o histórico de um repositório ao cloná-lo, use a flag --depth como no exemplo:

```
git clone https://github.com/curl/curl.git --depth=1
```

Answer (score -1):

$ git rm file.txt

Mudanças a serem submetidas:

```
    deleted:    file.txt
```

$ git commit -m "file.txt removido"

https://medium.com/@andgomes/git-removendo-arquivos-de-um-reposit%C3%B3rio-7eed699a035f

Answer (score -1):

No win, utilizando o comando del .git, ele deleta essa pasta oculta que é gerada (eu acho) a partir da execução do git init. Então como os demais comentários já ressaltaram é só dar os comandos novamente

```
C:\Users\YueNix\Projeto>del .git
C:\Users\YueNix\Projeto\.git\*, Tem certeza (S/N)? S

C:\Users\YueNix\Projeto>git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/YueNix/Projeto/.git/

C:\Users\YueNix\Projeto>git add .
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .editorconfig.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
```

Answer (score -3):

Com esse comando consegue remover todos os arquivos Traqueados.

```
rm -rf .git
```

No linux, não adianta remover a pasta `.Git` que o histórico volta.